# Correct way to make a DataMapper association

Tags: ruby, datamapper

I want to have a table of users. These users shall have n contacts and n messages..

My code is:

```
...
class User
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial, :key => true
  property :nickname, String

  has n, :contacts
  has n, :messages
end

class Contact
  include DataMapper::Resource

  belongs_to :user

  property :id, Serial, :key => true
  property :authgiven, String

  has 1, :user     
end

class Message
  include DataMapper::Resource

  belongs_to :user

  property :id, Serial, :key => true
  property :data, String
end

#apply models (validation etc.)
DataMapper.finalize
...
```

There are no errors initializing DataMapper, but when I try to create a new User or whatever, save always returns false... Can someone please point out what is wrong?

I'm quite new to DataMapper, it always worked for me with simple tables without relationships, so I believe it has to do with the way I declared the 1:n relationship...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you should remove that has 1, :user line from Contact model and you should be good.

Comment: Well ok thx I found that already... I replaced it with an Integer which should store the id... It would be more elegant as an association, though...